# mysql dup count and total

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like so,

```
name food  
A    Apple  
B    Banana  
A    Banana  
C    Apple
```

i want the distinct number of fruits and its total dup count.

```
food  count

2               4


SELECT food, COUNT(food) AS cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY food
HAVING (cnt > 1)
```

gives me total for each fruit. how would you modify this query to the result i want

Comment: Could you give an example of how the result should look?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(distinct food), COUNT(*) AS cnt
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional layer of aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_foods, SUM(cnt) as num_rows
FROM (SELECT food, COUNT(food) AS cnt
      FROM table
      GROUP BY food
     ) f;
```